# Retrieve Firebase RD Data with the JS library or Through a NodeJS Server?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am working on a project that uses the Firebase Realtime Database and I was wondering if it is best to use the JS library to retrieve data from the client side, or use the NodeJS library to take a client request and retrieve the data via the NodeJS server and send it back to the client.  Is there any advantages or disadvantages to either solution? (Security, ease of implementation, speed, etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When at all possible, the client SDK should be preferred.  Here's what you lose when proxying through a server:

- **No realtime updates.**  Unless you want to spend a lot of time coming up with your own way of shuttling updates through a websocket, the client will only ever be able to get a single update per request.  You won't have to ability to receive updates in real time, pushed to the client as they happen.
- **No security rules.** You won't be able to effectively control access to your database with security rules. Since the Admin SDK operates with full control over the entire database, you'll have to come up with your own way of figuring out if the client is allowed to read or write.  You could try to work around this by initializing the admin sdk on each request to scope it to a particular uid, but that's inefficient and too much extra code.
- **No client side cache.**  The Realtime Database client SDKs all cache data locally, so that future queries against data unchanged on the server are fast and cost less money.  You could always try to implement this yourself, but be prepared to spend a lot of time on that.
- **No offline sync.** When you write data using the client SDK, the data actually appears changed on the server (from it's own perspective), even if it's offline.  And when it comes back online, it will automatically sync those change to server without you having to do anything.  If you proxy through a server, you'll have to implement your own retry logic if you want this sort of behavior.

There might be some advantage going through a server, but it's highly dependent on what you're trying to do, and how you choose to compute what the savings is by doing so.

Comment: Thank you so much! This helped answer some other questions I had, too.